# Want to put condition in upload image in angular2

Tags: angular

I want to put condition when I submit or save form at that time file change function calling otherwise not. How to put that condition in below code ?

this is form template for image upload:

```
  <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && save()" #f="ngForm" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file">
            <img [src]="employee.profile_image_url" height="50" width="50">
        </div>
 </from>
```

Its a form save function in component:

```
save(): void {
    if (this.employee.bank_details == null) {
        this.employeeService.add_bankDetails(this.model, this.employee);
    }
    if (this.employee.current_address == null) {
        this.employeeService.add_addressDetails(this.model, this.employee);
    }
    if (this.employee.permanent_address == null) {
        this.employeeService.add_PaddressDetails(this.modelP, this.employee);
    }
    this.employee.full_name = (`${this.employee.first_name} ${this.employee.last_name}`);
    this.employeeService.update(this.employee);
}
```

Its a filechange event for image upload in component:

```
fileChange(event: any) {
    const imageFolder: string = this.employee.id;
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    const file: File = fileList[0];
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(`${imageFolder}/profile.jpg`).put(file)
    .then((snapshot) => {
    this.employee.profile_image_url  = snapshot.downloadURL;
 console.log(snapshot.downloadURL);
});

}
```

Comment: From your code I understand that you call fileChange() from the input's change event. Call it from the submit save() function...

Comment: yes but how can u explain please ..

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, I should do the following:

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && save(filename.value)" #f="ngForm" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input #filename type="file" placeholder="Upload file">
    <img *ngIf='isSaved' [src]="employee.profile_image_url" height="50" width="50">
</from>
```

**Typescript:**

```
save(fileName:string): void {
    if (this.employee.bank_details == null) {
        this.employeeService.add_bankDetails(this.model, this.employee);
    }
    if (this.employee.current_address == null) {
        this.employeeService.add_addressDetails(this.model, this.employee);
    }
    if (this.employee.permanent_address == null) {
        this.employeeService.add_PaddressDetails(this.modelP, this.employee);
    }
    this.employee.full_name = (`${this.employee.first_name} ${this.employee.last_name}`);
    this.employeeService.update(this.employee);
    //here you call file changing function
    fileChange(fileName);
}


fileChange(event: any){
  ....
  //add this at the end
  isSaved=true;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error message or it doesn't do anything?

Comment: no error msg.. its working properly but its done before submiting form

Comment: Could you explain again, what behaviour do you expect? Should the image be displayed after the submit and nothing before?

Comment: @Krunal, I guess this didn't help... but do you still need a help?